# template specification without definition

Tags: c++, oop, templates

I have the following code

```
template <typename Signature>
class Holder;

template <typename I, typename O>
struct Holder<O(I)> {
        // code here
        }
};

...
int main()
{
    ...
    Holder<int(double)> a;
    ...
}
```

I know that the declaration of one argument template parameter is necessary (since I'm calling the template class with one function-object parameter); but what I do not understand if in this case I'm really providing a template specification.
I thought that a specification of a template requires to have defined (not just declared) it, while in this case I simply declared the one-parameter template and then I defined in as a template with two parameter.
What is going on technically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is a valid template specialization (not "specification", that's a wrong word).

The primary (non-specialized) template being declared but not defined doesn't have any special effects. You won't be able to create an instance of it (just like of a non-template struct that's not defined), but that's all.

Comment: So why if in the specialization I only write `template <typename I, typename O> class<I> { ...}` the compiler complaints ` template parameters not deducible in partial specialization`?

Comment: @MaPo Because, as it tells you, `typename O` is unused (not mentioned in `<I>`).

Comment: But this works: 
`template <typename A, typename B> struct H2 { static void print() {std::cout << sizeof(A) << std::endl;}};`
So why it does not work in the specialization?

Comment: @MaPo Why wouldn't it? Template parameters of a specialization can't be specified manually, and always have to be deduced (from template parameters of the primary template, e.g. `I` and `O` can be deduced based on the knowledge that `O(I)` = `int(double)`). Your `H2` is not a specialization, so this limitation doesn't apply to it.

Comment: What I still do not understand in my (post) example is where the definition of the one parameter template takes places. You truly said that the  primary (non-specialzied) template being declared but not defined doesn't have any special effects. I completely agree. But so why at the end can I call the template class with one paramter? In the specialization it is templetized on two parameters.

Comment: @MaPo Template specializations are replacements for the primary template, which are used when template parameters of the primary template match the specified conditions. E.g. your specialization is used when `typename Signature` looks like `O(I)`, where `I` and `O` are arbitrary types. So, for example, if you tried `Holder<int> a;`, the specizalization wouldn't be used, and you'd get a error for trying to make an instance of a class that's not defined. Template parameters of a specialization can't be specified manually, so it doesn't matter if their amount differs from the primary template.